# Python Regex match every other word

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying and searching for a solution to match every other word in python using regex. The string is comma separated with unknown length.

Say I have the following string:

```
"keep, ignore, keep_this_too, ignore, keep_this_also, ignore"
```

I would like to be able to keep all the matching words as a list.

I tried writing my regex as:

```
((?P<keep>.*),)*
```

then using

```
result = re.match(regex, string)
print result.group(keep)
```

in attempt to printing out all matching words, instead I just get everything but the last word.

Thanks

Edit:

I cannot use any Python string operation.  The goal of this is to support any data format provided by researchers, to do this we are storing regex in a database for each format.
For example, they could provide a data format where we have to use the following regex:

```
"keep (ignore), keep (ignore), keep (ignore)"
```

Comment: Can your words have spaces in them?  That is, what if you had `"one, two, big data, four, five"`?

Comment: @RayToal Then it wouldn't be a word.

Comment: Thanks, just checking because you said the terms were _comma separated_.  But can you still clarify even further? So you are allowing spaces to separate words, also?  Or just commas or just spaces?  It makes a difference.

Comment: Why bother with regex at all? Split on comma, strip whitespace, and take those if index % 2 == 0

Comment: I added why I cannot use string operation above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` matches greedily (matched everything if possible); `.*,` match everything until the last `,`. To match non-greedily, use `.*?`.

And `re.match` returns only the first match. (and matches only at the beginning of the input string). (See [search() vs match()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match))

Using [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with the modified regular expression:

```
>>> s = "keep, ignore, keep_this_too, ignore, keep_this_also, ignore"
>>> re.findall(r'([^,\s]+)', s)
['keep', 'ignore', 'keep_this_too', 'ignore', 'keep_this_also', 'ignore']
>>> re.findall(r'([^,\s]+)', s)[::2] # using slice to get every other matches.
['keep', 'keep_this_too', 'keep_this_also']
```

or:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([^,\s]+)(?:,\s*[^,\s]+)?', s)
['keep', 'keep_this_too', 'keep_this_also']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I do not want to use any string operation (splice).

Comment: @David, Then, use the last code which just use `re.findall`. BTW `[..:..:..]` is called slice.

Comment: I apologize I did not see the second part, I will go try this out.

Answer (score 2):

You could still store `.split()` in a database instead?

```
String="keep, ignore, keep_this_too, ignore, keep_this_also, ignore"
String.split(",")[0::2]
```

Output:

```
['keep', ' keep_this_too', ' keep_this_also']
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexes already define what characters can appear in a word, namely `\w` denotes such set.
Hence:

```
In [1]: import re
   ...: re.findall('\w+', "keep, ignore, keep_this_too, ignore, keep_this_also, ignore")
   ...: 
Out[1]: ['keep', 'ignore', 'keep_this_too', 'ignore', 'keep_this_also', 'ignore']
```

If you want to ignore every other match simply use slicing:

```
In [2]: ['keep', 'ignore', 'keep_this_too', 'ignore', 'keep_this_also', 'ignore'][::2]
Out[2]: ['keep', 'keep_this_too', 'keep_this_also']
```

If you want to keep only strings that start with `keep`(or an other substring), simply use the pattern `keep\w*` instead of `\w+`:

```
In [4]: re.findall('keep\w*', "keep, ignore, keep_this_too, ignore, keep_this_also, ignore")
Out[4]: ['keep', 'keep_this_too', 'keep_this_also']
```

If what you are trying to match is not really a word, i.e. it can contain characters such as spaces, punctuation etc., then you can replace `\w` with `[^,]` in the regexes above to match everything except the comma.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
import re
re.findall("([^,]*), [^,]+[,]{0,1}", "keep, ignore, keep_this_too, ignore, keep_this_also, ignore")
```

But why not just use split and slice the result:

```
"keep, ignore, keep_this_too, ignore, keep_this_also, ignore".split(",")[0::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
s = ' keep, ignore,  keep_this_too  , ignore, keep_this_also, ignore '
print(s.replace(' ','').split(',')[0::2])
```

yields:

```
['keep', 'keep_this_too', 'keep_this_also']
```

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
>>> s = "keep, ignore, keep_this_too, ignore, keep_this_also, ignore"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)\W+\w+', s)
['keep', 'keep_this_too', 'keep_this_also']
```